# CMake and access name of special targets

Tags: c++, cmake

Is it possible to access the special targets (e.g. ALL_BUILD, INSTALL, RUN_TESTS, ZERO_CHECK) by some name to call commands like add_property() or add_custom_command() on them in CMake?

Use-cases for this pop up all the time in my code (e.g. running a target that is not part of ALL_BUILD when INSTALL is called).

Comment: What do you mean by "running" a target?

Comment: Invoking, calling, ... I'm not sure what the proper generalized term is.

Comment: Still no idea what you mean. Build the target? Or run a binary built by that target? Or something else?

Comment: I guess I mean building the target ... I just wanted to generalize the term as some targets are in fact just calling some command when being "build" (e.g. RUN_TESTS runs the tests and custom_targets just run the provided command).

Answer (score 4):

No, unfortunately it is not possible to refer to the pre-defined targets from within CMake code. Workarounds may exist for specific things you need to do, but the general answer is no.

For the specific case you mention (building a target when building `INSTALL`), you might have luck with something like this:

```
install(CODE "EXECUTE_PROCESS(${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build other_args_here)")
```